# Wi-Fi with no data

Tags: wi-fi, data-connection, samsung-galaxy-s-4

This has always bugged me, but I really don't know the best way to ask it (sorry if this is a duplicate):

Some Wi-Fi networks that I use require secondary authentication (via a browser, etc), and some are unreliable (they stop working intermittently). When this happens I get no data on my phone even though I have a data plan. (Galaxy S4, ATT FWIW).

Is there a way to configure my phone to use my cell data when the connected Wi-Fi is not working\unavailable, etc?

Comment: This seems like something that you can automate with Tasker...? I have a task that when I am not connected to any WiFi my mobile data turns on, otherwise it is off.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to go 4G when not on Wifi?

Comment: 4g, 3g, whatever. What I want is when I am connected to Wifi, if said Wifi is not sending\receiving data, that the data would go through my mobile data instead.

Comment: Did [my answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/49857/23379) help?

Comment: Yes, I +1 it but I'm waiting to the end of the bounty to sort out the best answer. Thanks.

Comment: Aww!! I thought *I* am the one who gave the *there is nothing currently out there* answer. Sad!! :(

Comment: it was more than just that, @geffchang's advice is useful above and beyond... it works "most of the time"

Comment: Fine then. :) But mine is **THE** answer for *this question*. So could you at least accept it? And when you reply to a comment, please tag the other person using **@** *<username>*

Comment: Like others have already pointed out, some models, including my Samsung Note 2, can detect internet access and whether login/password is required, so it's obviously technically possible to check is. Unfortunately I need to go into network settings to see that there is no Internet access - I'd like the phone to simply disable the AP and switch to mobile network (3G) instead to ensure continuous internet access. A friend tell me his Iphone has this functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging, I have to decide that what you are trying to achieve is not possible since there is no way to check whether there are additional login requirements necessary for the connected Wi-Fi networks.

You may be able to check the connectivity of the Wi-Fi network with the methods mentioned by both [geffchang](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/49828/23379) and [NoBugs](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/49854/23379). *But*, since the connections with additional authentications *literally* give you the internet access to login to their network, the said apps and methods  (even the tasker) will sadly be of lesser use.

But the [Network Tester](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.gc.networktester&hl=en) app [suggested by NoBugs](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/49854/23379) seems promising even though it cannot switch the connections.

You can *use an app like [Auto WiFi / 3G Switch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=notus.com.tr.autowifi3gswitch&hl=en)* to do the switching automatically. This app can be used to disable Mobile Data / 3G connection automatically when your device is connected to a WiFi network and re-enable Mobile Data when your device is disconnected from WiFi network. Again of course, the app cannot detect whether or not there are additional authentications.

Finally you are left with manually switching and toggling your mobile data and Wi-Fi. You can **use an app like [3G WiFi Connection Mode](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.itomainu.android.connectionmodewidget&hl=en)**.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `Settings > Connection > Wi-Fi > Left-click (soft menu) > Advanced > Check for Internet service`?

NOTE: I have an S4 (build XXUBMGA)

Comment: That might just be it. I'll test it more this afternoon and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I think it might work if the connection is down, but if the Wifi connection requires a login it does not seem to work.

Comment: @javamonkey79 I see. Well, if it's able to connect to their log-in page (but gets denied access), then it looks like it has Wi-Fi access. This is a problem I have also encountered before, but I guess the only option was to really log-in. If I couldn't, I'd disable the Wi-Fi and get on 3G data. I hope somebody else can offer a solution.

Comment: Yeah, this is still a helpful suggestion. +1

Comment: This seems to be about as close as it gets. From what I can tell, there is nothing currently out there that does this, but it seems like it wouldn't be that hard to do.

Comment: On my Nexus 4, when I'm on a Wifi network that requires a login, it will set a notification "Login to wireless network" shortly after connecting.  It checks against a known-value page in [CaptivePortalTracker](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/net/CaptivePortalTracker.java?source=cc#L324)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [iNetify](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=network&fdid=net.luniks.android.inetify) or [Network Tester](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=network&fdid=org.gc.networktester&fdpage=2) to check for wifi connectivity?

Comment: Ideally, I am looking for something that toggles connectivity rather than checks for it. iNetify looks promising and Network Tester looks useful. Perhaps if no suitable solution is found I'll submit a feature request or fork the code. Thanks, +1

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to configure my phone to use my cell data when the
>   connected Wi-Fi is not working\unavailable, etc?

Assuming you are talking about Wifi being activated, then in this case, Wifi and Cellular Data are exclusive, you cannot have one activated and yet use the other. A flip-flop operation, switch on Wifi, Cellular Data is off, switch off Wifi, Cellular Data is on. Cannot have both!

- Check the firmware - perhaps a newer update is available? *What version of Android are you referring to?*

Quite possibly, Izzy's solution of using Tasker might suffice, this was [answered](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49976/how-to-disable-cellular-when-wifi-is-present/49985#49985) recently?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible up to Android 4.2.  Some convention they need to follow that's why if mobile phone is connected by WiFi (no matter internet connection is there or not to WiFi router or device by which your phone is connected) then it will not get connect by Mobile Data. 
May be you will find some application on google store but I am not sure. Because if some application do this then they need to change at kernel level or they need to customize the Operating System.

Comment: Do you have documentation for this? I mean, it seems like it wouldn't be that hard for an application to simply turn WiFi off if it isn't actually transmitting data. Look at the apps [@NoBugs](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/49854/37987) suggested.